# My VSC always opens a file when something is executed in shell - How to prevent this?

Tags: python, shell, visual-studio-code

I am sorry if this question is maybe trivial but i couldn't come into the formal description of the problem, thus have not really found the answer yet.

So with basic english, everytime the shell executes some programm, 
ex.

```
jupyter notebook
```

or

```
virtualenv <name>
```

I expected the shell to:

run a notebook server

or

make a virtual environment folder

instead the file which responsible for the execution is opened in my VS Code.
I don't know what option did I chose while i installed VSC so maybe i'm missing something here?

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed default opening program of *.py file into powershell and it shows this error. This is going forward

when executing jupyter notebook

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management.Automation, 
Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The 
paging file is too small for this operation to complete. 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x800705AF)
```

and when executing virtualenv :

```
Thread failed to start.
```

I got this link for some insight:

[Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management.Automation'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473734/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-management-automation)

will update here for further solution.

Comment: this is really trivial. you just have to change the default executing program of *.py into python.